# Windows updateWarning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, xampp

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/School/OneDrive - Noorderpoort/PHP/htdocs/Jaar1/Blok1/Les7/oefening16.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0

After a long windows update I suddenly get this error when I try to open a php file through the localhost.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Problem is caused by the new 'On Demand' feature in OneDrive.  MS/OneDrive creates placeholder files in your OneDrive folders, and downloads them as needed - but apparently not in response to php attempting to access those files.

Solution is to disable on-demand, or, mark your php files for 'always keep on this device':  In explorer, right click on the folder that you are using for your php files  (ie your webserver document root directory) and select the option "Always keep on this device".  This will force OneDrive to keep a valid/full copy of the file,  and php should no longer have a problem reading it.

You may need to wait a while for the files to be downloaded - OneDrive seems to queue them up.

Comment: Same issue for me! However, the files was downloaded and still not working right. I had to move it out of the folder all together. Would be nice to have OneDrive functionality though!

Comment: Dropbox user here. This was the same issue for me and making available offline resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem with MAMP for Windows. The problem occurs when you use your OneDrive folder for hosting your files.
It seems the Fall Creators Update introduced it.
I've worked around the problem and moved my files to a non-Onedrive location.
See also: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f445b2f1-01e1-4380-8b8f-28f331b30d41/fall-creators-update-onedrive-interfering-with-wamp-web-server

Comment: Is there a solution that involves not moving folders from OneDrive?  I want to be able to still use it to have the benefits of cloud backup and using across different devices, but also having same problem as you guys. Not found a solution yet.